# Tensorflow model to Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I want to use pretrained `SqueezeNet` model implemented in `Tensorflow` in another Python package. The problem is that the current version of `Tenorflow` [does not support Python 3.7](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20444) and also including whole Tensorflow package as a requirement is not a good idea since it is very space consuming and can be an additional source of issues in the package. The best option would be to avoid `Tensorflow` as a requirement.

Is there any option to convert `Tensorflow` model to operations in `Numpy` or any other representation which is lighter. I do not need the support for training the model since it is already pretrained. I will use the model just for prediction purposes. The solution must have an option to be packed in a Python package (installable through `pip`).

Any other suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try exporting your model to tflite and see if you can afford to depend on that. There is no currently supported way to automatically convert any tensorflow model to numpy but you might be able to do so manually by inspecting your model.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try with to export the model to the tflite.

Comment: I do not find the solution to run `tflite` from Python without having `Tensorflow` installed (and then using its lite interpreter). I think I will need to find another solution.